How do I save and later load Azure AnalyzeResult object in python?
I have generated document analysis result using:
 with open(pdf_path, "rb") as f:
     poller = document_intelligence_client_sections.begin_analyze_document(
         "prebuilt-layout", f.read(), content_type="application/pdf", 
         output_content_format=ContentFormat.MARKDOWN, ) 
 result = poller.result()
 
 type(section_layout)
 >> azure.ai.documentintelligence.models._models.AnalyzeResult  # Want in this format! 

I have saved the result using ... as_dict() as follows:
with open("data/section_layouts/result.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(section_layout.as_dict(), f)

Now, as I load the JSON using,
with open("result.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

I get the data in dictionary as expected. However, I wanted to have the data in in AnalyzeResult class format.
More information:
I am using DocumentIntelligenceClient.
from azure.ai.documentintelligence import DocumentIntelligenceClient

document_intelligence_client_sections = DocumentIntelligenceClient(
    endpoint=service_endpoint, credential=default_credential)

with open(pdf_path, "rb") as f:
    poller = document_intelligence_client_sections.begin_analyze_document(
        "prebuilt-layout", f.read(), content_type="application/pdf", 
        output_content_format=ContentFormat.MARKDOWN,
)
result = poller.result()

So, the type of the object is different:
type(section_layout)
azure.ai.documentintelligence.models._models.AnalyzeResult

And it does not have .to_dict() and .from_dict() as well.

The solution was rather simple.
Importing AnalyzeResult from azure.ai.documentintelligence
from azure.ai.documentintelligence.models import AnalyzeResult

#and the casting the dictionary previously saved with .as_dict()

    # Saving,
    with open("test.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(section_layout.as_dict(), f)

    #Loading,
    with open("test.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    data = AnalyzeResult(data)

I wish #Microsof #Azure #DocumentIntelligence team would have added this in their documentation!


I get the data in dictionary as expected. However, I wanted to have the data in in AnalyzeResult class format.

You can use the below code to get the data in AnalyzeResult class format.
Code:
import json
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import AnalyzeResult

endpoint = "https://xxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
api_key = "xxxxx"
document_intelligence_client_sections = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(api_key))

pdf_path = r"C:\Users\xxx\demo.pdf"

with open(pdf_path, "rb") as f:
    poller = document_intelligence_client_sections.begin_analyze_document(
        model_id="prebuilt-layout", document=f.read(),
    )
    section_layout = poller.result()

with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(section_layout.to_dict(), f)  # Use to_dict() to save as JSON
    
with open("result.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Convert the dictionary back to an AnalyzeResult object
analyze_result = AnalyzeResult.from_dict(data)

# Now you can work with the AnalyzeResult object
print(type(analyze_result)) 

The above code use the to_dict() method to save the AnalyzeResult object as a JSON file and then use the from_dict() method to convert the JSON data back to an AnalyzeResult object.
Output:
<class 'azure.ai.formrecognizer._models.AnalyzeResult'>



Hi @Venkatesan! Thanks a million for your time. However, it did not work for me. I have provided more information in the original question, please review? Thanks.

Glad to know that you resolved your issue.
